# Make a shape move up on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

Currently, I have a canvas which is the width and height of your browser. Using this code:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var circle = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;


for(var i = 0; i < numofcirc; i++)
{
  name = "circleno" + i;
  var name = new Array(3); 
  name = [height, rndwidth, rndradius, vel]
  circles[i] = name;
}


var vel = 2;
var circles = [];
var numofcirc = 1;
var name;

function DrawCircle()
{
  rndwidth = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  height = height - 13;
  rndradius = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 5);

  circle.beginPath();
  circle.arc(rndwidth, height, rndradius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  circle.fillStyle = "white";
  circle.fill();
  circle.translate(0,6);
}

function Move() 
{
  circle.translate(0,6);
  requestAnimationFrame(Move);
}

Move();
DrawCircle();
```

I am able to create a circle placed randomly at the bottom of your screen. The bit of the code that isn't working is this:

```
function Move() 
{
  circle.translate(0,6);
  requestAnimationFrame(Move);
}
Fireworks();
```

When `DrawCircle();` is called, the circle is drawn on the canvas. Then `Move();` is called. Becuase it uses `requestAnimationFrame` the function `Move();` repeats over and over again. I want this code to move that circle drawn ealier up by 6, so it looks like the circle moving up.
If I add the `circle.translate(0,6);` to the `DrawCircle();` function and change the `DrawCircle();` function to this:

```
function DrawCircle()
{
  rndwidth = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  height = height - 13;
  rndradius = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 5);
  circle.beginPath();
  circle.arc(rndwidth, height, rndradius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  circle.fillStyle = "white";
  circle.fill();
  circle.translate(0,6);
  requestAnimationFrame(Move);
}
DrawCircle();
```

then it keeps on drawing rows of circles across the screen which are all separated by 6.

Is there any way I can just make one single circle move up on your screen when it is drawn?

Thank you for you help @HelderSepu !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at examples and build from that...

Here is one simple case:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 170;

var circles = []
circles.push({color:"red",   x:120, y:120, r:15, speed:{x: 0,    y: -0.5}})
circles.push({color:"blue",  x:80,  y:120, r:20, speed:{x: -0.5, y: -2.5}})
circles.push({color:"green", x:40,  y:120, r:5,  speed:{x: -1.5, y: -1.0}})

function DrawCircle() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circles.forEach(function(c) {
    c.x += c.speed.x;
    c.y += c.speed.y;
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = c.color;
    context.fill();
    
    if (c.x + c.r < 0) c.x = canvas.width + c.r
    if (c.y + c.r < 0) c.y = canvas.height + c.r
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(DrawCircle);
}

DrawCircle();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

But if you are going to do a lot more animations you should consider using a game engine,
 there are a lot of great open source ones:
https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: How would I get this to work with say 2 circles and have them move at different speeds. I don't think I need to use a game engine since I don't have enough animations to warrant the use of one. Thanks.

Comment: A gaming engine is not only need when you have a lot of animations, it also simplifies a lot of your code... I will update my code to show multiple circles

Comment: @DreamingInsanity I updated the code to have multiple circles

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting a sequence of circles, it looks like you're not clearing the canvas when a frame is drawn. Simply draw a white rectangle that fills the canvas whenever a new frame is requested, then draw your circle.

The method you provide as an argument to `requestAnimationFrame` is responsible for drawing a complete image on the canvas which replaces whatever was there during the previous frame.